# Regex to replace special characters with '\' symbol

Tags: php, regex

I would like to replace special characters like `'`, `"` with `\'`, `\"`, because they cause errors when creating a query with these values.

Any one know the regular expression to replace `'`, `"` (single quote, double quote) with `\'`, `\"`?

Comment: use `addslashes` function

Comment: Use database library implementation. For example `mysqli_real_escape_string` if you use mysqli library. Not `addslashes` as @Seti sugests.

Comment: This is for PHP, not for the database - so i presumend he dont need it for database therefore no `mysqli_real_escape_string` is required.

Comment: @Seti "create query" means likely database. Even if it's not database but let's say url query, there are always more targeted methods then `addslashes`.

Comment: Intriguing but for me it can mean really many thing  -  there are query var in php and so on.

Comment: `addslashes` solves my problem. Thank U for support

Answer (score 0):

```
$replaced = preg_replace("/',\"/", "\\',\\\"", "',\"");
```

https://php.net/preg-replace